Implementing the Contrastive Loss' Temperature with PyTorch
I am attempting to implement the temperature parameter within a contrastive loss, and I have no idea if I'm doing well. However, it seems to be working because the learning seems to be harder than without the temperature parameter.
First, here's my training loop.
initial_temperature = 1.0
temperature_decay = 0.1
for epoch in range(num_epochs_vae):
    contrastive_loss_total = 0  # Initialize total contrastive loss
    epoch_counter += 1

    temperature = initial_temperature * (1 / (1 + temperature_decay * epoch))
    for batch_idx, data in enumerate(tqdm(train_dataloader)):
        optimizer_vae.zero_grad()
        
        # Pass Forward
        mu, logvar = vae(data)

        # Generate pairs of latent vectors and their labels for contrastive loss
        z1, z2, labels = generate_contrastive_pairs(mu, logvar, data, temperature)

        # Calculate contrastive loss
        contrastive_loss = vae.module.contrastive_loss(z1, z2, labels)

        # Backpropagation
        contrastive_loss.backward()
        optimizer_vae.step()

        # Accumulate total contrastive loss
        contrastive_loss_total += contrastive_loss.item()

Then, here's my generate_contrastive_pairs function.
threshold = 1.0

def generate_contrastive_pairs(mu, logvar, data, temperature):
    batch_size = data.size(0)

    # Reparameterize to obtain latent vectors
    z = vae.module.reparameterize(mu, logvar)

    # Randomly select positive and negative pairs
    idx1 = torch.randint(0, batch_size, (batch_size,))
    idx2 = torch.randint(0, batch_size, (batch_size,))

    # Ensure that idx1 and idx2 are not the same index
    idx2 = torch.where(idx1 == idx2, (idx2 + 1) % batch_size, idx2)

    # Obtain latent vectors corresponding to the selected indices
    z1 = z[idx1]
    z2 = z[idx2]

    # Calculate distances between latent vectors
    distances = torch.norm(z1 - z2, dim=1)

    # Apply temperature scaling to distances
    scaled_distances = distances / temperature

    # Define labels: 1 for similar pairs, 0 for dissimilar pairs
    labels = (scaled_distances < threshold).float().unsqueeze(1)  # Add an extra dimension to match the shape of sim_scores

    return z1, z2, labels

And finally, my loss function.
    def contrastive_loss(self, z1, z2, label):
        projection1 = self.projector(z1)
        projection2 = self.projector(z2)
        sim_scores = self.contrastive_head(torch.abs(projection1 - projection2))
        criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
        contrastive_loss = criterion(sim_scores, label)
        return contrastive_loss

